# How could I use 'fmi2GetDirectionalDerivative'?

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

I am trying to get the model Jacobian matrix from FMU, according to the following literature, I could use `fmi2GetDirectionalDerivative` to do this, but I am not sure what I need to do exactly.

My question is:

1. Could I call this function in Dymola or MATLAB?
2. A screenshot or an example would be very helpful.

https://ep.liu.se/ecp/132/091/ecp17132831.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with calling DLL functions in MATLAB but this is an example in Python. FMPy (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) has these wrappers for running FMUs in python.

I've tested this for a simple model I've written here([How to access model jacobian from FMU or Dymola without analytical jacobian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59580902/how-to-access-model-jacobian-from-fmu-or-dymola-without-analytical-jacobian)). In this case, knowns are value references of either states or inputs, unknowns are value references of derivatives or outputs.

I have had success extracting the Jacobian when exported through Dymola as Model Exchange FMU but not Co-Simulation FMU.

```
def get_jacobian(fmu, vr_knowns, vr_unknowns):
    """
    populates jacobian from list of knowns and unknowns
    can be only called after the current sim time and inputs are set
    """
    jacobian = []
    try:
        for vr_known in vr_knowns:
            for vr_unknown in vr_unknowns:
                jacobian.extend(
                    fmu.getDirectionalDerivative(
                        vUnknown_ref=[vr_unknown],
                        vKnown_ref=[vr_known],
                        dvKnown=[1.0]
                    ))
        print_status(f'Jacobian Elements: {jacobian}')
    except Exception as e:
        print("[ERROR] cannot compute jacobian at current timestep")
        print(f"[ERROR] {e}")
```

I use this code snippet to collect the value references for states and derivatives using FMPy:

```
# get FMU model description object
model_description = fmpy.read_model_description(
    os.path.join(fmu_path, fmu_filename)
)

# collect the value references
vrs = {}
for variable in model_description.modelVariables:
    vrs[variable.name] = variable.valueReference

# collect list of states and derivatives
states = []
derivatives = []
for derivative in model_description.derivatives:
    derivatives.append(derivative.variable.name)
    states.append(re.findall('^der\((.*)\)$',derivative.variable.name)[0])

# collect the value references for states and derivatives
vr_states = [vrs[x] for x in states]
vr_derivatives = [vrs[x] for x in derivatives]
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a paper from Mitsubishi Electric at the recent NAM Modelica Conference 2020 that might be related.